# How to set the height of Angular material's mat-expansion-panel-header while being expanded?

Tags: material-design, angular-material-6

I wanted to set the height[say 32px] of mat-expansion-panel-header which I was able to. However, while expanding the panel, the height goes to material's default height [I guess 64px] and then sets it to my custom height[32px]. This resulted in a flickering-effect. You may check the behavior at https://angular-v138d6.stackblitz.io

Pl advise if there is a way to override the mat-expansion-panel-header height while the panel is 'being expanded'

Comment: please refer below question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747188/material-angular-accordion-header-title-height

Answer (score 3):

If you read the documentation of [Angular Expansion Panel Header](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api#MatExpansionPanelHeader%20there) there are two properties `collapsedHeight` & `expandedHeight`. You can use these to set the height.

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header collapsedHeight="56px" expandedHeight="56px">
  <mat-panel-title>Personal data</mat-panel-title>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded {
height: 4rem
}
```

If required you can also use

```
/ngdeep/.mat-expansion-panel-header.mat-expanded {
height: 4rem
}
```

Comment: Adding this will start flickering on expansion panel toggle.